# Unable to print Printer Configuration for Zebra KR403

Tags: android, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl-ii

I am having trouble printing anything using the Zebra KR403 Printer using my Android app.

To debug I try to print the configuration using the below command:

```
String ZPLCommand = new String();
        ZPLCommand += "^XA"; // Start command
    ZPLCommand += "^MN" + "k"; 
    ZPLCommand += "~WC";
    ZPLCommand += "^AF^FDTESTLINE^FS";
    ZPLCommand += "^XZ"; // End command

    DiscoveredPrinterUsb discoveredPrinterUsb;
    Connection conn = discoveredPrinterUsb.getConnection();
    conn.open();

    ZebraPrinter printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(conn);
    printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(conn);
    printer.sendCommand(ZPLCommand);
    conn.close();
```

The printer is able to print about 80% of the configuration (till Calibration Field) and then it stops...I see a blinking red status LED.

I have tried researching the same without any success. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~WC` is an immediate command which prints the config label, not a calibration command. Try sending that by itself and then sending the rest of the label.

Did you mean to send a `~JC` to calibrate? Also, I don't know if you want to calibrate in the middle of a format, that's usually done only once and then the printer doesn't need to be calibrated again

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, my program would not print any character or image that I send it. But it does prints something when I pass '-WC' (I'm not trying to calibrate the print). Do you recommend I calibrate it using "-JC" once and then try to print statements?

Comment: Yeah, if it's already calibrated, you don't need to recalibrate it. Will it print even a simple ZPL format? Also, the ^MN is a media tracking setting change, so you shouldn't send that every time either... Does this print anything?   ^XA^A0N40,40^FO100,100^FDHello World^FS^XZ

Comment: No, it doesn't print anything I put in the ZPL except what comes through '-WC' :(

Comment: does it move paper? or does absolutely nothing happen?

Comment: Hi Ovi...thank you for your responses. Turns out the issue was not with the code but with how the paper was being fed to the printer. The sensors had trouble on the paper feed due to the angle at which the paper was being inserted. Cheers!